# CSS Centering by using Line-Height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering, line-height

I don't understand why there is a gap between the paragraph and the div element, below is my code. I am new to CSS.

```css
.center {
      line-height: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 3px solid green;
      text-align: center;
     }
.center p {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="center">
    <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.
    </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Without more information on what you're trying to do, its hard to give the best answer. p tags have margins by default, so if you set `margin: 0;` on `.center p` then it will appear how you expect. You don't need `vertical-align: middle;` in this case.

Comment: @Temani Afif There are two problems with this code. The `margin` should be set to 0, *and* the `line-height` should go inside the `p` and not the `div`. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I have just done what you said, yes, the gap get much smaller, however a very narrow gap still exist....why?

Comment: remove vertical-align AND add margin:0

Comment: @MichaelHaddad it's a duplicate because the real issue is to center a text and we have a ton of duplicate for such question. margin:0 is a sub issue

Comment: Hi Temani, I have removed the vertical -align and add "margin: 0: there, however, there is a very narrow gap between the border and the paragraph, which can be seen clearly even the gap gets much smaller....

Answer (score -1):

Your paragraph has a margin-top by browser defaults. Set it to margin-top: 0; and there won't be gap.

Comment: Thanks and i have done what you said.  The gap becomes much smaller, however a narrow gap still exist between the border and the paragraph....

Comment: Add this to the .center div: width: fit-content;